# im looking at passing access data to word from subforms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to get data from a subform into word, if there is more that 1 row of data(eg 1st row = 3 cats, 2nd row = 1 dog (Me![pets_Information]![PetType]) ) I can only get the 3 cats to copy to word, I am importing to Legacy Forms - Text Form Field.

What I need to achieve is :- 3 Cats, 1 Dog in the one text field

There seems to be very little of this that I can find on the internet, always finding just from the main form and nothing really regarding subform/childforms

There are 3 tables that I need to set this up for all have their own keyID's

```
Function FillLetter()

    Dim appword As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim path As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    ''''''Chaange for which computer''''''''''''''
    path = "F:\Access Stuff\Job for John - PSA\Homestay Provider Information.docx"
    'path = "G:\Access Stuff\Job for John - PSA\Homestay Provider Information.docx"
    Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set appword = New Word.Application
        appword.Visible = True
    End If
        Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(path, , True)
        With doc
            .FormFields("txtClientsFName").Result = (Me.Title) & " " & (Me!ClientFirstName) & " " & (Me!ClientFamilyName) '''works
            .FormFields("txtAddress").Result = (Me!Address) '''works
            .FormFields("txtSuburb").Result = (Me!Suburb) & ", WA " & (Me.PostCode) '''works
            

            .FormFields("txtContactType2").Result = (Me![Contact_Information]![ContactType]) & " " & (Me![Contact_Information]![ContactDetails])

            .FormFields("txtFamily").Result = (Me![Family_Information]![Relationship]) & " " & (Me![Family_Information]![Age])
            
            .FormFields("txtPolice").Result = Me!LegalCert '''works
            .FormFields("txtCosts").Result = Me!CPW '''works
            .FormFields("txtMeals").Result = Me.IEMeals '''works
            
            .FormFields("txtPets").Result = (Me![Pets_Infomation]![PetType])
    
            .FormFields("txtHobbies").Result = Me!HobbiesInterests '''works
            .FormFields("txtInstitute").Result = Me.Institution '''works
            .FormFields("txtTravel").Result = Me.ToUniCollege '''works
            .FormFields("txtOther").Result = Me!OtherInformation '''works
            .Visible = True
            .Activate
        End With
    
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set appword = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RecordsetClone to get the underlying subform data

**Add this function to your Form (make sure constants match your subform/field):**

```
Private Function GetPetTypes() As String

    Const SUBFORM_NAME  As String = "Pets_Infomation"
    Const PET_TYPEFIELD As String = "PetType"

    Dim strPetList  As String

    With Me(SUBFORM_NAME).Form.RecordsetClone

        If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            ' Start with first record
            .MoveFirst

            Do While Not .EOF
                If strPetList <> "" Then
                    strPetList = strPetList & ","
                End If
                strPetList = strPetList & .Fields(PET_TYPEFIELD)
                .MoveNext
            Loop

            ' Go Back to first record in case it needs to be reused
            .MoveFirst
        End If
    End With

    GetPetTypes = strPetList

End Function
```

**Then replace this line:**

```
   .FormFields("txtPets").Result = (Me![Pets_Infomation]![PetType])
```

**with this line**

```
   .FormFields("txtPets").Result = GetPetTypes()
```